# .htaccess error 500 : </ifmodule> created at the end of the and don't know why

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-500

I'm having an issue with my .htaccess file. i've notice that approximatly 10h after a restor of the file a new line is created : `</ifmodule>`. Because of this, my site is facing many 500 errors each day.

My file :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Les directives (lignes) entre « BEGIN WordPress » et « END WordPress » sont générées
# dynamiquement, et doivent être modifiées uniquement via les filtres WordPress.
# Toute modification des directives situées entre ces marqueurs sera surchargée.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've restor my file like 10 times, and the 2 last lines are always created from nowhere...

Here my log errors :

```
.htaccess: </ifModule> without matching <ifModule> section
```

Comment: Try deleting those last two lines and then change the file permissions of your .htaccess file to 644.

Comment: WordPress will "try" to maintain this file. Make sure the line-endings are consistent. `\n`, not `\r\n`.

Comment: @cabrerahector That would be the old mistake of trying to handle the symptom instead of fixing the actual cause.

Comment: Yep, I realize that @arkascha. OP does need to figure out what's causing the issue, this is just a measure to maybe prevent the site from breaking while debugging the problem. Apologies if that wasn't evident from my previous comment.